# How to save List<String> via ActiveAndroid?

Tags: android, activeandroid

I have a `List` of `Strings` in my Object :

```
public ArrayList<String> trailersURLs = new ArrayList<>();
```

If need to save String I use

```
@Column(name = "trailer")
public String trailerUrl;
```

But how i can save(actually annotate) `List<String>` via ActiveAndroid?

Comment: Is `save()` not working?

Comment: @m0skit0 **but how to annotate List?**

Comment: You need to iterate with each item and then save each item with table.

Comment: @RajanBhavsar the question is about how to persist List in Object. Not about how persist List of Objects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837792/storing-hashmapstring-object-with-using-activeandroid-library please check this link.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace your collection with array and make specific TypeSerializer, for example saving to db with json format.

more information [github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Type-serializers](http://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Type-serializers)

```
 public class MyClassArraySerializer extends TypeSerializer {
        private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
        @Override
        public Class<?> getDeserializedType() {
            return MyClass[].class;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getSerializedType() {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object serialize(final Object o) {
            if (null == o) return null;
            final String json = gson.toJson(o);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize(final Object o) {
            if (null == o) return null;
            final MyClass[] myClassItems = gson.fromJson(o.toString(), MyClass[].class);
            return myClassItems;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `MyClass` is this name of my object?

Comment: yes refer to this link for more information https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Type-serializers

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/235#issuecomment-240141691)

Just use `List< String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

No need to worry about to create other objects.

For me this is the easiest way to save List< String> in ActiveAndroid

```
public class ListGsonSerializer extends TypeSerializer {

    private final static Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public Class<?> getDeserializedType() {
        return List.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getSerializedType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String serialize(Object data) {
        if (null == data )
            return null;

        return gson.toJson(data);

    }

    @Override
    public List<String> deserialize(Object data) {
        if (null == data)
            return null;

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList =  gson.fromJson(data.toString(), List.class);
        return stringList;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you have multiple List types in your project ? not only List<String>